# Making an inactive mailbox active

Tags: settings, mail.app

I made one of my mailboxes inactive. How do I make it active again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Preferences, Accounts, click on the account and then the "Advanced" tab. There will be a check box next to "Enable this account."